# TFS - Is there a way to reset revision number?

Tags: version-control, tfs, revision, changeset

Hello
We're currently migrating from SVN to TFS, and when I created the Team Project I did a lot of stuff (created work items, commited a lot of stuff, imported the projects, changed a lot of files)

Is there a way I can reset revision number without recreating the Team Project?

(I don't need to delete the past changes or anything, I just want my next commit to be "changeset 1" again)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why is this important? Just aesthetics?

Comment: Yes Oded, just aesthetics. I don't want my 100+ changesets showing up with no reason, and my past failed builds turning my reports ugly and inaccurate. I just want it to be clean and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that.  Also recreating the team project won't help as revision numbers (changeset numbers) are global to the entire source control repository, not just the projects that are in it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I see. No problem then, I guess we'll just ignore it. A bit sad, though.